# what's the error in my code, it's not showing the popup box(Android)?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, popup

While clicking the popup button it's not showing popup box and it's force close the application. Here i included my code (xml and java) for my native android application.

> popup.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonPopup"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onButtonInPopup"
    android:text="Dismiss this PopupWindow">
</Button>
```

> Java code

```
public void onButtonPopup (View target) {
       // Make a View from our XML file
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
             this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPopup));

       m_pw = new PopupWindow( layout,  350,  250,  true);
       m_pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inflating `popup.xml` and defined the parent as `(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPopup)`. This ViewGroup will not create until you inflate the layout. and `findViewById` will work only after you set the layout in `setContentView`.
Try inflating using this -

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
```

Comment: how to disappear this popup box?

Comment: You are using `PopupWindow`. According to this link [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) the `dismiss()` method will dispose the window. :)

Answer (score 0):

@babu: If you want to implement the Custom popup for your desire layout then use this:
Its help me lot and hope also help you.

See this demo:

```
    public class ExPopup extends Activity {

    Dialog myDialog;
    Button myButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ClkBtn);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDialog = new Dialog(ExPopup.this,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
                myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog);

                //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                //myDialog.setTitle("My Dialog");
                myDialog.setCancelable(true);
//                Button button = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
//                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//                @Override
//                    public void onClick(View v) {
//                  myDialog.dismiss();
//                    }
//                });
//    
                myDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }


 }
```